# Nodejs, Request and Dot notation

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am trying to get first name of a facebook user via their API.
This is my code

```
  var user = request("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/"+psid+"?fields=first_name,last_name&access_token="+token, function(err, res, body) {  
    console.log("name: " + body.first_name);
    console.log("body: " + body);
  });
```

This is the result:

```
name: undefined
body: {"first_name":"Anton","last_name":"Rosato"}
```

Why name is undefined ?

Comment: What does `console.log("Body type: " + typeof body)` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow @yBrodsky advice or add options object into request with
`{json:true}`. This will automatically add 'Content-type: application/json' into your request and parse response as json.

```
reqeust.get(url, {json:true}, callbalck)
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined because body is a string. Cast `body = JSON.parse(body)` before trying to read first_name.

Comment: I am not sure, check RidgeA answer. Not sure if you get json response in body.

Comment: @xRobot: `body` **is** JSON. It needs to be parsed to access the data.